# Is it possible to connect an Xbox One wireless controller to the Xbox 360 wireless receiver for PC?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers, xbox-one

I got 2 Xbox wireless controllers for my PC along with a wireless receiver adapter. I'm considering getting some more, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea now that the Xbox one and its controller are out (meaning the 360 controller will be phased out soon and games might use a new XInput api that's incompatible with the 360 controller)

So I was wondering if it's possible to connect an Xbox one controller to the xbox 360 wireless receiver for PCs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot connect the Xbox One controller to the 360 receivers. They are different controllers with different tech and mechanical workings inside, so they share 0 compatibility. You can, however, just plug the XB1 controller in using any old micro USB cable (they are common household items nowadays) and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you cannot connect an Xbox One controller through the Xbox 360 wireless receiver. You can buy the [Microsoft Xbox One Controller + Wireless Adapter for Windows 10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015IX3X3E) ($62.99 USD) that includes the adapter you will need. A better option however would be the bluetooth model as it does not require the rather bulky wireless dongle. This particular model was introduced with the [Xbox One S](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one-s). Pay close attention though, only these *specific* models of controllers have the universal internal bluetooth adapter. These controllers can be identified by the front face plate which is one solid piece of plastic as seen on the left in this figure:
[image]

If you don't have Windows 10, or are experiencing connection issues, refer to my post [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311375/186704) where I posted a work-around for such problems. You can purchase the [Xbox One Wireless Controller here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/controllers/xbox-wireless-controller) for $59.99 USD.

*Note: that Microsoft no longer sells the model that includes the dongle from their marketplace.*

Comment: Is the bluetooth model completely compatible with Windows? Or do I need to download sketchy reverse engineered drivers and replace the bluetooth stack (like how Dual Shock 3 bluetooth worked)

Comment: It uses standard Bluetooth 3.0 communication protocol. I've synced an Xbox One bluetooth controller with Windows 7, 8, and 10.

Comment: And it just autodetects installed drivers and configures it automatically, like how it does when you plug in a wired Xbox controller?

Comment: Yes, if you happen to require an update for the controller (which is _most_ likely), use the firmware update tool in the Windows Xbox app or by syncronizing the controller with an Xbox One that has an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, no. As for the future, very unlikely. Both controllers use a different protocol to communicate with their respective receivers. While it might theoretically be possible, it would need to be done on the receiver side.

Comment: Interessting. I wonder if it's simply a protocol difference, or if the radio frequencies are also different. I think if it was just the former then maybe the receiver can be hacked somehow

Comment: I think to remember that the throughput is higher, which, for me, would mean that to not induce any lag, either the compression needs to be better or the radio frequency, or at least the breadth of the allocated band, needs to be different. As most Xbox owners with a One will likely also own a 360, choosing a different frequency seems to be the safe choice to avoid any interferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a usb cable to connect the Xbox controller (even though it’s wireless it still has a usb entrance) to the 360 console. This should sync the controller to the Xbox 360 console.

Comment: It should work I will use this in my friends console

Answer (score -2):

Now you can. 
New drivers are out and about so download your drivers for PC and pair your XBox One controller.
Good luck

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where can one find these new drivers?

Comment: This is incorrect.  The drivers allow for USB connection between PC and XBox One Controller, but still no wireless support.