# Is it possible to connect Xbox One S controller to Windows 7 via Bluetooth?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, windows-7

I bought an Xbox One S controller to use over Bluetooth with my PC, however Microsoft only appears to support the controller in Windows 10.

I'm running Windows 7, so is there a way to fix or hack it to get the controller working via Bluetooth in Windows 7?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you *can*, however you need a specific model of controller. In the image below, take note of the top-front of the controllers. Xbox One controllers that *are* Bluetooth compatible have a solid face plate with no gaps, whereas non-Bluetooth models have diagonal splits along the shoulder buttons:

[image: Bluetooth Xbox One controller on the left, non-Bluetooth controller on the right]

You will also need to update the controllers firmware. To do this, either connect the controller to your Xbox One while connected to the Internet, or connect it to your PC with a micro USB cord. See [this](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.xbox.com/xboxone/controllerupdate&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjf9e-HnMfUAhVR0WMKHfiVA78QFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNHbOOyuPwqkUW0XZHxabQEMUQ2wzg) link for updating the firmware through a PC.

To pair the device, hold the sync button on the top-left of the controller while you search for new Bluetooth devices on your PC. It *should* appear as "Xbox One wireless controller for Windows".

If you still have issues connecting your controller, you can also use the [Moga Serial to Windows Interface](https://github.com/Zel-os/MogaSerial) tool to use the controller as an XInput HID.

I have used all of these methods successfully on Windows 7, 8, and 10.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, unfortunately it did not work, as the moga serial does not recognize my xbox one controller and thus unable to communicate with it, however it gave me a lot of ideas about the possibility of actually doing this, and currently im working (albeit very slowly) on checking and hopefully contributing and customizing Zel-os and/or nefarious codes to achieve that result (but i wont hold my breath as my responsibilities are increasing exponentially lately and im trying to enjoy my free time)...
again thank you very much for the time and effort, truly appreciate it.

Comment: @mike Did you ever get this working on Windows 7 via Bluetooth? It's seemingly impossible for me.

Comment: @Mr. Mendelli This didn't work at all for me on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to stem from rather evil active efforts by MS to make 7 actively avoid the driver required, a guy over on this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3vuvg8/manually_download_xbox_one_controller_driver_for/ Has for the past 2 years been kindly keeping us supplied with the driver, install it and mess around with the wired/wireless stuff on the controller and it should work.

Spent a week trying various fixes his driver was what worked.

Comment: That's the wired/USB driver; not the wireless Bluetooth one.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3vuvg8/manually_download_xbox_one_controller_driver_for/cxqw6mz/

download drivers, install, reset your PC, connect via bluetooth and enjoy.
It worked for me.

I`m using ugreen usb bluetooth 4.0 adapter, windows 7 64 bit